# How to check rethinkdb process

Tags: ubuntu, rethinkdb

I have rethinkdb running on the background and on startup accordign to https://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/start-on-startup/ (Quick Setup).

But how do I find the process in my server terminal?
If I type rethinkdb it says it's already running / listening to that port.
RethinkDb is running but I would like to know how I can access it on my ubuntu server regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RethinkDB doesn't has a console client for shell access like MySQL. You can use RethinkDB admin dashboard as a REPL tool. It's usually run on port 8080 so you can use 127.0.0.1:8080 to reach it. But since it's on server and you don't want to bind it to public IP, you can use SSH port forwarding as in https://rethinkdb.com/docs/security/#via-a-socks-proxy

You can learn more about the dashboard and RethinkDB in general https://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/quickstart/

If you still want a CLI REPL, give this a try: https://github.com/stiang/recli

RethinkDB has an issue to work on a official cli: https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/189